# Bare metal OS can't use locals

Tags: c, ram, osdev, bare-metal

I just started to get into OS development, emulating a raspi2 (cortex a7) with qemu.
Right now I'm stuck because I can't use local variables when the cpu is in user mode.

here's what my main program looks like

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t function_with_locals() {
    uint32_t l1 = 5;
    uint32_t l2 = 3;

    return l1 - l2;
}

void kmain() {
    __asm("cps 0b10000"); // cpu in user mode

    uint64_t res = function_with_locals();

}
```

if I set a breakpoint in `function_with_locals` this is the frame info from gdb

```
(gdb) i frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x0:
pc = 0x9d4c in function_with_locals (kmain.c:10); saved pc = 0x9d84
called by frame at 0x10
source language c.
Arglist at 0xfffffff8, args:
Locals at 0xfffffff8, Previous frame's sp is 0x0
```

basically I can't use any locals because they are stored outside of the RAM I defined in the linker script when the cpu is in user mode.
However if I change it to SVC mode `l1` and `l2`are well within the RAM.

Any pointers on what might cause this ?

Thanks

Comment: So you have not properly defined and initialized your stack. You have to fix your linker script and perhaps the startup code. BTW, "Bare metal OS" is an oxymoron.

Comment: it was indeed in the startup code thanks. Also I'm currently setting up a stack for each cpu mode: is this required ? or let's say I won't use the FIQ mode, can I skip initialising the stack pointer ?

Comment: You can if you absolutely sure that it will never be in this mode